# ${\rm End}(\bigoplus V)=\bigoplus({\rm End}(V))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum

I saw in a demonstration that they used the fact
$${\rm End}(\bigoplus V)=\bigoplus({\rm End}(V))$$
for $\bigoplus$ finite and $V$ a space vectorial. He tried to prove it but I don't have a clear idea. Could you give me a suggestion for this proof?

Answer (score 3):

Use additivity of Hom, and note the sums go over different index sets
$$\begin{align}
{\rm End}\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n V\right) &= {\rm Hom}\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n V, \bigoplus_{i=1}^n V\right) \\
&= \bigoplus_{i=1}^n  \bigoplus_{i=1}^n {\rm End}(V) \\
&= \bigoplus_{1\leq i,j\leq n} {\rm End}(V).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Probably also nicer to use $V^{\oplus n}$ notation

Answer (score 0):

You can think of $\operatorname{End}(V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_n)$ as matrices $(T_{i,j})_{i,j = 1}^n$ where $T_{i,j} : V_i \to V_j$.

So if all the $V_i$'s are 1-dimensional then $T_{i,j}$ is represented by a scalar and hence $(T_{i,j})$ is just an $n \times n$ matrix. This makes sense based on what we know: $\operatorname{End}(\mathbf{F}^n) = \operatorname{Mat}_{n}(\mathbf F)$.

More generally, we represent $\operatorname{End}(V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_n)$ as [block matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) of the appropriate shape.

Comment: Not sure about claim about block matrices at the end. $\oplus_i End(V_i)$ would be block matrices (no cross terms). As you mentioned, this one has cross terms $V_i\to V_j$

Comment: @Ben Those are block diagonal matrices which are special cases of block matrices.

Comment: I’m suggesting a correction of the last line where it says $End(...)$ is block matrices, but for any vector space (including this case), $End(...)$ is ring isomorphic to all matrices $M_n(k)$ and not a ring of block matrices like $M_n(k) \times M_m(k)$

Comment: @Ben It seems like you're not making a distinction between a block diagonal matrix and a block matrix. If you click the Wikipedia link you will see that not all block matrices are block diagonal matrices. I am talking about the general case.

Comment: Oh i see! Thanks